# Is there a Java to Flash compiler?

Tags: java, flash

GWT is pretty cool: write in Java, we build an Ajax app.

Is there something similar for Flash? Code in Java, we convert it to Actionscript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't use any myself but found these from osflash.org

This seems to be doing something of the sort. http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/transform/. Then there is [haxe](http://haxe.org/doc/intro) which doesn't do Java as far as I know but might be worth looking into.

**UPDATE:**
I just found out that ANTLR will also talks ActionScript. You'll have to define a formal grammar that translates other languages into ActionScript (http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3ActionScriptTarget)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is available yet, but Joa Ebert showed a Java to SWF compiler at last Flash on the Beach. You can read about it in [Compiling Java and C# to SWF](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2009/09/28/compiling-java-and-c-to-swf/).

Cheers,